# How to invoke xkbcomp?

Tags: keyboard, xorg, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, xkb

When I'm trying to run this `xcbcomp $DISPLAY original.xkb` I'm getting this:

```
No command 'xcbcomp' found, did you mean:
 Command 'xkbcomp' from package 'x11-xkb-utils' (main)
xcbcomp: command not found
```

How to invoke it ? Or should I make it another way ?
I'm trying to emulate numpad on keyboard as described here (I know: that's very different distro):
https://forum.manjaro.org/t/how-to-emulate-numpad/51120

Comment: `xcbcomp` is not the same thing as `xkbcomp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead, do `xkbcomp $DISPLAY original.xkb`
You made a typographical error.